# WS_EX_LAYERED Transparency issues Windows 10 Creators Edition

Tags: windows, windows-10, directx

I have been working on a window overlay as part of a data verification application and during a recent update to windows 10 Creators Update WS_EX_LAYERED no longer applies Alpha transparency correctly.

Removing the WS_EX_LAYERED flag gives the expected result but the window is now hit tested. (clicks don't pass through to the window below)

With WS_EX_LAYERED:

[image: With WS_EX_LAYERED]

The blue box is supposed to have an alpha transparency (And did in previous versions of windows 8 - 10)

Expected result with alpha:

[image: expected result]

Is there a possible workaround specifically for windows 10 Creators update? either allowing a window to be clicked through like ws_ex_layered or am I missing some new flag that was added?

Code Replicating the issue:

https://github.com/akuseru/aero-overlay

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615946/c-d3d9-alpha-blending-with-creators-update). You probably also apply color key for layered window attributes.

Comment: Answer in linked question above solved it for me.