# Transparent WinForms not working after Creators Update

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, transparency, creators-update

I have an app that uses a transparent background of a Windows Form with an embedded PictureBox.  I draw in the picture box and with versions of Windows 10 before the Creators update I could click on the visible parts of the picture box image as well as the buttons on a toolbar at the bottom of my form.  I use the transparencyKey color setting to match the form background color.  Here is a snippet of C# code for the Form.

```
ecgPictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
this.BackColor = Color.Gray;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Gray;
```

After the Creators update, when I click on visible parts of the form (including buttons on a toolbar at the bottom) most of the time the click "falls through" to the underlying window, though there a few odd points where the click does appear to be absorbed by the form.  This all worked perfectly on previous versions.  Here are two pictures
[Not working (Creators update)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgfdW.gif)
[Working! (earlier version Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN6sB.gif)

Anyone else have a problem with WinForms transparency after the Creators update, and any idea what is going on or how to fix it?

Comment: It is a Creators bug, not just affecting Winforms apps, fairly remarkable that it doesn't generate more bug reports.  The canonical [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615946/c-d3d9-alpha-blending-with-creators-update) but it merely says "don't use TransparencyKey".  There is a stupid hack, taking advantage of another bug that's been around much longer, set the transparency to Color.Red.  That makes the button work but the window is no longer click-through.

Comment: You are right, the buttons work if I make the BackColor Color.Red, but I still can't click on the PictureBox.  I will work around by making the Form semi-transparent by setting the Opacity.  Hope they fix this.